# What is the verb form of 'to apply sequins to'?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I was talking with my boyfriend today about getting an altar cloth for some tarot cards and he said, "Good, you can bedazzle it yourself!"

To which I said, "I wouldn't bedazzle it, I would sequent it...or is it sequin it?....I would apply sequins to it."

What is the correct verb form of 'to apply sequins to'?

Comment: The adjective *sequined* is in the [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sequined), even though it doesn't list *sequin* as a verb. Does that mean that we can infer that the verb *sequin* exists?

Comment: What kind of heathenish stuff is going on over there?

Comment: I was going to suggest _bedazzle_ and then I saw it was already in the question...

Comment: @PeterShor: An adjectival form '*-ed*' may be possible from nouns which are not also verbs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *American Heritage Dictionary* gives *sequin, v*: "To affix sequins to (a garment, for example)."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced sequin is a verb. The "mainstream" dictionaries only include entries for nouns.

Did find this though, a complete conjugation http://www.the-conjugation.com/english/verb/sequin.php

I would use "add sequins" - I will add sequins to it.

Comment: I find it curious that, in Wordnik (which aggregates online dictionaries), only AHED lists a verb form for [sequin](http://www.wordnik.com/words/sequin).